# How to implement Tag search?

Tags: algorithm, tags, elasticsearch, hashtag

I've designed a news hub system which read Rss links and stores whole news in the database. Now I want to implement a search system using tags. Each news has it's own tags. There are lots of algorithms to implement this but I don't know what is the most common to have the best performance. Currently I'm using Elastic search database and I use multiple keyword search. Which one of these are the best?
1- to store tags in a list or a string with a separator and search among them?
2- work like a relational system and have a table of tags, and a table of news tags to have a record for each news tag. and 5 records for 5 tags of one news
3- another algorithm which I don't know

Comment: What is the scale of the data? How many articles? How many hashtags?

Comment: millions of documents. with thousands of hash tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ElasticSearch will handle that very well and you have multiple ways of implementing that behavior.

What you want is a parent child relationship between a news article (parent) and its tags (children).

Depending on whether you need to update the hashtags after indexing your news articles or not, you could go with storing them in the news article or as separate documents pointing to the news article document as their parent.
See more details here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

You mentioned a choice between storing the tags as a list or a comma separated string. Go with the list as that is more idiomatic and ElasticSearch can handle json objects (you would actually analyze the string and turn it into a list of token anyways).

Comment: Do you have a full system design explanation which supports this tag architecture?

Comment: updated link for blog : https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch

Answer (score 10):

Seems like you want something like the [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)

This is an index, that for each term (hashtag in your case) holds a list of document ids which contain this hashtag.

For example, if you have 3 documents: d1,d2,d3 with the hash tags:

```
d1: #tag1, #tag2
d2: #tag3
d3: tag3, #tag2
```

The inverted index will be:

```
#tag1: d1
#tag2: d1,d3
#tag3: d2,d3
```

It is fairly easy using the inverted index to find all documents that contain a certain term (hashtag in your case), by simply going over the list the is attached to this term.

This datastructure is also very efficient for union (or queries) and intersection (and queries).

This DS is very popular for information retrieval for full text search and also is often used in semi-structured search.

For more information, you can read about [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) in general. [Mannings Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookonlinereading.pdf) represents this Data structure in [the book's first chapter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/boolean-retrieval-1.html).

Comment: Do I have to implement it my self or databases like Elastic Search can handle this for me?